What's the intuitively best option for preprocessing images of varying aspect ratios and resolutions?
We've got a complex pipeline that produces a crop of the minimum possible subset image that includes all useful information. We've got a number of customers using various models on these images, and we don't control the models used. I'm trying to figure out how we should serve these images, of varying size and shape, to customers, based on an intuitive understanding I currently lack for which form is the most useful.
Options (feel free to add your own):

Stretch images to fit a standard shape

Keeps all data, but distortion could be difficult for some model architectures to deal with


Crop images to a standard shape

Likely a non-starter, as there's often important information in the edges of the images


Pad images with some solid color

Could be difficult for some model architectures to deal with


Pad images with a transparency matte

Could be difficult for some model architectures to deal with, but easier for human developers to edit than a solid-color matte that could collide with real data



I know there are options for models that can use variable image sizes and resolutions, likely fully-convolutional models, but we don't decide the models, the users of the data do. We're planning to offer everything in its unedited shape, but for beginner customers who want the easiest pre-edited form to deal with instead, what option is intuitively most likely to perform best across a wide array of image models? Most of these models are likely transformer-diffusion models, but not all of them.
